# How can I use one function for different JS classes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, javascript-objects

Assume I have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

```
function ClassA(){
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 'a';
    this.z = false;
}
```

-

```
function ClassB(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 'b';
    this.z = true;
}
```

And I want to use one function for these two as prototype:

```
var foo = function(){
    if(this.z){
         window.alert(this.y + this.x);
    }
}
```

Is it safe to use it like

```
ClassA.prototype.foo = foo;

ClassB.prototype.foo = foo;
```

because I assign **same function** object for **different classes**.

OR is there any way to define *interface* (like JAVA) and use inheritance somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to use it like...

#### Yes

This is perfectly fine. Unlike python methods, javascript functions know nothing of the class they belong to.

Comment: Ok, I trust you but I wonder how do you handle this kind of situations in JS. You do the same thing too or is there any smarter way?